# It's correct to call a class/function inside __init__?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm not sure if this is a correct approach of doing it, but i have a class   with some functions using the same class on another file. The question is, its ok to call a class one time under the **init** ? what kind of complications could it have if i do it with a class that uses queries/inserts or http requests?. Or should i avoid doing it?

Bellow, an example of what i mean:

the way i'm doing:

**classfileA.py**

```
class StackExample:

    def __init__(self, input_a, input_b)
        self.var_a = input_a
        self.var_b = input_b

    def say_hello()
        print "My bacon is : " + self.var_a
        print "But still boss as : " + self.var_b
```

--

**file2.py**

```
import classfileA

class Action:

    def __init__(self, input_a, input_b)
        self.var_a = input_a
        self.var_b = input_b    

    def test_a()
        start = classfileA.StackExample(self.var_a,self.var_b)
        start()

    def test_b()
        start = classfileA.StackExample(self.var_a,self.var_b)
        start()

    def test_c()
        start = classfileA.StackExample(self.var_a,self.var_b)
        start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run = action('my love','blind')
    run_cm.main()
```

What i think i can do:

**classfileA.py:**

```
class StackExample:

    def __init__(self, input_a, input_b)
        self.var_a = input_a
        self.var_b = input_b

    def say_hello()
        print "My bacon is : " + self.var_a
        print "But still boss as : " + self.var_b
```

--

**file2.py**

```
import classfileA

class Action:

    def __init__(self, input_a, input_b)
        self.var_a = input_a
        self.var_b = input_b
        # call inside __init__
        self.start = classFileA.StackExample(self.var_a,self.var_b)


    def test_a()        
        self.start()

    def test_b()
        self.start()

    def test_c()
        self.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run = Action('my love','blind')
    run.test_a()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It will work, and I'd suggest you actually do it the way you're asking. The only thing to note is the name `someClass` which is never defined. `classfileA.StackExample` however would work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's fine in sense that nothing will blow up in regards to the `someClass.StackExample` object and the calling object.